# Prove that the condition number of the stiffness matrix in Laplace equation is bounded by $h^{-2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method, condition-number

I'm a little stuck trying to estimate a condition number in FEM context. I would like to prove the following:

Consider the stiffness matrix $K$ for piecewise linear functions on
a quasi-uniform mesh in one dimension of the Laplace equation. Prove that
the condition number of $K$ is bounded by
$\mathcal{O}(h^{−2})$. (Hint: use inverse estimates.)

The matrix is given by $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \ldots & \ddots & & & \ddots \\
\ldots & & &  0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
\ldots & & & & 0 & -1 & 2  
\end{pmatrix}$

I do not know how to start to be honest, because i do not know how to estimate the smallest and largest eigenvalues. In dimension one i think that i can get explicitly the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but i would like to estimate it, because is more general.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Can you write out the stiffness matrix given the specifications above? The spectral properties of this tridiagonal matrix have been studied extensively and you will likely get better help (or potentially find a related question on this forum) with the matrix explicitly given.